# Partition function of a two-level system of N independent particles in the classical limit

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Consider a system of $N$ independent particles at a temperature $T$. Each particle can be in two distinct energy levels, with respective energies $\varepsilon_1 = \varepsilon_0$ and $\varepsilon_2 = 2\varepsilon_0$. The goal is to compute the canonical partition function for the whole system in the *classical limit*. Since the particles are independent, the global partition function will depend only on the $N$-th power of a monoparticular partition function, namely $Z_1(T, V)$, which I have calculated and results to be
$$
Z_1(T, V) = \sum_{k = 1}^{2} \Omega(k\varepsilon_0)e^{-\beta n \varepsilon_0} = e^{-\beta \varepsilon_0} \left (1+e^{-\beta \varepsilon_0}\right)
$$
where $\beta = 1/(k_\text{B} T)$.

The main question of mine regards the notion of *classical limit*, and how it does relate with the distinguishability of the particles. In this such limit, if the particles were distinguishable, the global partition function should be
$$
Z(T,V,N) = \left [Z_1(T, V)\right]^{N}
$$
and if they were indistinguishable, then
$$
Z(T,V,N) = \frac{\left [Z_1(T, V)\right]^{N}}{N!}.
$$
My intuition tells me that the particles should be classically distinguishable since one can completely identify them by their position and momentum. However, on the other hand, in the classical realm, there's not any exclusion principle preventing two particles from occupying exactly the same energy, position and momentum state, and so these particles should be indistinguishable.

Having exposed all of this, could someone clarify me the notion of classical limit and how it should be applied to this particular problem? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, since you are talking about distinguishable particles, you want to recover the Maxwell-Boltzmann from the quantum statistics of Fermi-Dirac or the Bose-Einstein statistics. In general the statistics agree in the dilute limit, i.e. when $N\to0$. Note that this only makes sense for the grand canonical ensemble, you cannot obtain it from the canonical ensemble.

In your case, you can verify this explicitly. I'll change the energies to $\epsilon_\pm = \pm$. In the grand canonical ensemble, you just need to calculate the partition function per orbital since the total partition function is obtained using the product:
$$
\mathcal Z = \mathcal Z_+\mathcal Z_-
$$
For Maxwell-Boltzmann:
$$
\mathcal Z_\pm^{MB} = e^{e^{\beta (\mu-\epsilon_\pm)}}
$$
For Fermi-Dirac:
$$
\mathcal Z_\pm^{FD} = 1+e^{\beta (\mu-\epsilon_\pm)}
$$
For Bose-Einstein:
$$
\mathcal Z_\pm^{BE} = \frac{1}{1-e^{\beta (\mu-\epsilon_\pm)}}
$$
So:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal Z^{MB} &= e^{2e^{\beta\mu}\cosh\beta} \\
\mathcal Z^{FD} &= 1+e^{2\beta\mu}+2e^{\beta\mu}\cosh\beta \\
\mathcal Z^{BE} &= \frac{1}{1+e^{2\beta\mu}-2e^{\beta\mu}\cosh\beta}
\end{align}
$$
All three expressions have the same asymptotic behaviour when $\beta\to0$ and $z = e^{\beta\mu}\to 0$ (i.e. $\mu\to-\infty$ in such a way that $-\mu \gg T=1/\beta$). In fact, you can check that each individual factor
$$
\mathcal Z = 1+2e^{\beta\mu}
$$

It is not easy to build intuition from the partition function alone, it's better to rather calculate the chemical potential at fixed number of particles. In this case, you'll find that:
$$
\mu = T\ln N
$$
at leading order in $N$, which is independent of the number of orbitals and their energies.

Hope this helps.